# Testing React form components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

In my tutorial-like application I have a **AddForm** component:

```
var React = require('react');
var Input = require('react-bootstrap').Input;
var TeamActions = require('../actions/team_actions.js');

var AddForm = React.createClass({
  handleFormSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = this._trimmedValue(this.refs.name);
    var rating = this._trimmedValue(this.refs.rating);

    if (name && rating) {
      TeamActions.addTeam(
        {name: name, rating: rating}
      );
      this._clearField(this.refs.name);
      this._clearField(this.refs.rating);
    }
  },

  _trimmedValue: function(field) {
    return field.getInputDOMNode().value.trim();
  },

  _clearField: function(field) {
    field.getInputDOMNode().value = '';
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
          <Input label="Name" type="text" placeholder="Name" ref="name" />
          <Input label="Rating" type="text" placeholder="Rating" ref="rating" />
          <Input bsStyle="primary" type="submit" value="Add!" />
        </form>
    );
  }
})

module.exports = AddForm;
```

TeamActions:

```
var McFly = require('mcfly');
var Flux = new McFly();
var TeamConstants = require('../constants/team_constants.js');


var TeamActions = Flux.createActions({
  addTeam: function(team) {
    return {
      actionType: TeamConstants.ADD_TEAM,
      team: team
    }
  }
});

module.exports = TeamActions;
```

As you can see, I'm using McFly and React-Bootstrap here.

Now I want to test it, using jest.

I would like to have following test cases:

1) if someone tries to submit a form with empty inputs, nothing should happen (to be more specific - there should be no interaction on TeamActions mock)

2) if one submits a form with valid name and rating, then there should be a proper call to TeamActions mock

3) if one submits a form with valid name and rating, then name and rating inputs should be cleaned.

How do I test it? Should I access the DOM somehow, using react's TestUtils?

Should I somehow simulate form submission? If so, how do I do that?

And last thing - my AddForm depends on TeamActions. By writing:

```
jest.dontMock('../add_form.js');
```

is jest instructed to mock all those dependencies (react, react-bootstrap, team_actions) or should I somehow mock TeamActions myself?

**// edit:**

Because someone said I asked too much quuestions in one topic, to be more specific:

How can I simulate a form submission with specific payload, using TestUtils?
Do I need to mock TeamActions myself or is is mocked for me automatically?

Comment: Can you simplify this to be a specific question? There are multiple issues and each is too broad for a good easily digestible StackOverflow answer.

Comment: Sure, will edit in a second.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I've edited my question. To be honest, I see one big issue with main topic 'how do I test it?'. And a proper code snippet will solve all my problems.  But I tried to be more specific anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React TestUtils allows you to simulate form submission:

```
var addForm = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(AddForm(null));
var form = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(addForm, 'form');
TestUtils.Simulate.submit(form);
```

The way I would test the actions is by manually mocking out `addTeam`. Before simulating anything in the test, do something like:

```
var TeamActions = require('../actions/team_actions');
TeamActions.addTeam = jest.genMockFn();
/* then simulate submission... */
expect(TeamActions.addTeam).toBeCalledWith({name: 'name', rating: 'rating'});
```

For testing the input values, just use the refs.

```
addForm.refs.name.getDOMNode().value = 'Some Name';
/* perform some action that should clear input */
expect(addForm.refs.name.getDOMNode().value).toEqual('');
```

**edit**

To answer your edited question, it looks like you actually don't need to manually mock `addTeam`; I just tried it out and it seems like Jest figured out how to mock the McFly actions.

Comment: Thank you. It works, but it's quite ugly. Isn't there a way of submit a form with parameters? I mean, something like TestUtils.Simulate.submit method, which takes a json as a parameter?

Comment: All the TestUtils,Simulate.{event} methods allow you to pass your own mock-event as the second parameter, so I think you could theoretically do something like: TestUtils.Simulate.submit(addForm, { target: [{value: 'name'}, {value: 'rating'}] })

Comment: Still kinda ugly, though. :-/ Usually when I have this type of situation I just allow the values to be specified as optional component props.

Comment: Did you try the approach with additional parameter? Looks a little bit better than this ugly playing with DOMNode values. Optionally, I could provide a method on my component, which allows to fulfill form, but I don't like this approach.

Comment: The problem with additional parameter approach is that I think you'd have to change `handleFormSubmit` to get the values from the event object rather than the refs, so you're making the app code a lot uglier for the sake of the tests. Personally, I'd just stick with the refs or the TestUtils helpers for finding DOM nodes. If somebody has a more elegant approach, I'd love to hear it, though.

Comment: What I did eventually, is exposing setters and getters like methods for those values. So now I'm doing this ugly chain inside my component class. Not elegant at all, since I don't like to expose setters/getters, but probably better than coupling my tests with te implementation details.